# Dot TK as a domain name for my own email server?

Tags: mail-server

"Dot TK - It's FREE! But if you pay, you get a lot more! When you pay **you own the domain legally**, you may sell or transfer your domain and you do not have **the minimum user requirement of 25 hits per 90 days.** Pricing starts at just USD 6.95 per year. It's all up to you!"

I'm going to make my own linux email server, for me only, and I want a nice free domain name. Dot Tk seems to offer me that opportunity but does the statement above mean that I'll have to send atelast 25 email in 90 days or else?

Answer (score 4):

Use the "make as email server" option on dot tk at registration. You will need to send 10 emails every 90 days to each email forward account.

Answer (score 0):

I registered a .tk domain, lets call it beep.tk (not my actual domain)

I registered beep.tk with custom dns, so I got an account on freenom.com

From there i proceeded to set up the MX records using freenom dashboard, pointed them to my email server's IP address and it worked:
postmaster@beep.tk would send/receive email just fine

About the required traffic rules: I have owned beep.tk for a good couple of months and I have had no contact about being revoked, but it might help that i used it as a website too

Although only myself and a select few others knew beep.tk, I had over 1199 hits in one month, i think from crawlers such as google, since i registered my email server with them

Comment: does this still works? i couldn't send nor receive any mail with my postfix. I can't register at zoho mail either.

Comment: 5 years later, I've moved on to a .com domain. For $8 a year or whatever, it's much better than tk. Note that they "stole" my one domain that got popular. Imagine users of your site getting redirected to porn adverts.

Comment: @Kyle, Are/were they adverts or porn adverts?

Comment: @pacerier porn adverts. Cannot recommend tk to anyone with capacity to spend a few dollars a year